# probably css priority bug in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#access a, #access a:visited {
line-height: 2em;                 //<- Chrome uses these
padding: 0 1em;
}
#access ul ul a {
line-height: 1em;                 //<- Firefox uses these
padding: .5em .5em .5em 1em;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<nav role="navigation" id="access">
[...]
  <div [...]>
    <ul [...]>
      <li [...]> [...] </li>
      <li [...]> [...]
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li [...]> [...] </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>    
</nav>
```

Which selector has the higher priority?

```
#access a, #access a:visited
```

or

```
#access ul ul a   <- Is supposed to have the higher priority
```

one of the two browsers (Firefox or Chrome) seems to interpret them wrong

an easy fix was to give the second selector a classname

```
-> #access ul ul.sub-menu a  <- works for both
```

if this can considered to be a bug then I will report it to Mozilla/Google

EDIT: two pictures of Fiddle (1 in Chrome and 1 in Firefox):
Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: I've just created a jsFiddle that shows `#access ul ul a` having the higher priority in Chrome. Can you create one yourself in case I've made a mistake in replicating your problem?

Comment: Works as expected for me http://jsfiddle.net/C8449/1/ both browsers use `#access ul ul a`

Comment: I have updated it with the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/C8449/3/ and there it is again; the same mistake, maybe you know whats going wrong, I can make screenshots of Firebug and Chrome Console

Comment: does somebody have any clue? I have send feedback to Google already but what do you think? Bug, or not?

Answer (score 2):

"#access a:visited" has higher specificity than "#access ul ul a".  If you run through the algorithm at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity the former has a specificity of (0, 1, 1, 1) while the latter is (0, 1, 0, 3).

Your modified selector ("#access ul ul.sub-menu a") has specificity (0, 1, 1, 3).

The reason that Firefox is ignoring the line-height styling inside the :visited rule is explained in http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy and in particular in the "It limits the CSS properties that can be used to style visited links" paragraph.